# Alguien sabe cómo puedo convertir mi código para que me imprima los resultados en el IDE o en mi PC?

Tags: c, arduino

Estaba haciendo un proyecto en Arduino UNO, sobre un medidor de velocidad y distancia pero la pantalla está defectuosa. Quisiera saber si los resultados que me da el sensor se me puede imprimir en la pantalla del IDE, o por defecto generar un archivo o que se muestre en mi PC los valores de la velocidad y distancia.

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);// RS,E,D4,D5,D6,D7
// defines los números de los pines
const int trigPin = 9;
const int echoPin = 10;

// defines variables
long duration;
int distance1=0;
int distance2=0;
double Speed=0;
int distance=0;

void setup() 
{
lcd.begin(16, 2);// LCD 16X2
pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT); // Definimos al trigPin como Output o Salida
pinMode(echoPin, INPUT); // Definimos al echoPin como Input o Entrada
pinMode( 7 , OUTPUT);
Serial.begin(9600); // Iniciamos la comunicación serial
} 


void loop() 
{

//Calculando la velocidad
distance1 = ultrasonicRead(); // A continuación llamamos a la función ultrasoninicRead()

delay(1000);//Damos un retraso de 1 seg

distance2 = ultrasonicRead(); // A continuación llamamos a la función ultrasoninicRead()

//Fórmula para cambiar distancia, dividiéndolo por el tiempo
Speed = (distance2 - distance1)/1.0; //Como el retraso es de 1 seg, lo dividimos por 1

//Visualización de la velocidad en pantalla
Serial.print("Veloc. in cm/s  :"); 
Serial.println(Speed);
lcd.setCursor(0,1); 
lcd.print("Veloc.  cm/s ");
lcd.print(Speed); 

// Indicador LED
if (distance >0 && distance <5) 
{
 digitalWrite( 7 , HIGH);
 delay(50);                  // Espera un segundo
}

if (distance > 5 && distance <10 ) 
{
 digitalWrite( 7 , HIGH);
 delay(50);                  // Espera un segundo
 digitalWrite( 7 , LOW);    // Apaga el led
 delay(50);                  // Espera un segundo
}

if (distance >10  && distance < 20) 
 {
 digitalWrite( 7 , HIGH);
 delay(210);                  // Espera un segundo
 digitalWrite( 7 , LOW);    // Apaga el LED
 delay(210);                  // Espera un segundo
 }

 if (distance >20  && distance < 35) 
 {
 digitalWrite( 7 , HIGH);
 delay(610);                  // Espera un segundo
 digitalWrite( 7 , LOW);    // Apaga el LED
 delay(610);                  // Espera un segundo
 }


 }

 float ultrasonicRead ()
 {
 // Liempia el trigPin
 digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
 delayMicroseconds(2);

// Establece el trigPin en estado HIGH o ALTO durante 10 microsegundos
digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
delayMicroseconds(10);
digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);

//LEE EL echoPin, Y RETORNA EL TIEMPO DE VIAJE DE LA ONDA SÓNICA EN MICROSEGUNDOS
duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);

//Calculando distancia con la siguiente fórmula
distance= duration*0.034/2;

// Se imprime la distancia en la pantalla
Serial.print("Distancia in cm : ");
Serial.println(distance);
lcd.setCursor(0,0);
lcd.print("Dist. in cm ");
lcd.print(distance);
lcd.print("   ");
return distance;

}
```

En ese código se muestra los valores en la pantalla que lamentablemente se averió.
Como se puede observar, en el código se indica que la luz parpadee a una determinada distancia.
El sensor funciona muy bien, el led prende, las conexiones están verificadas, pero el único problema es que me imprime en la pantalla, pero quisiera modificarlo para que me pueda imprimir en archivo txt o en el misme IDE por ejemplo.
Hay alguna forma?
Acepto sugerencias. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Puedes utilizar programas que sirven como interfaz de I/O con el puerto serie. Putty, Termite, Realterm, Teraterm.. cualquiera de ellos te vale y son gratis. Simplemente establece comunicación hardware con la placa y tu PC con cualquier cable serie (RS2323 mismamente), configuras el programa para captar el COM que tienes y podrás ver todo lo que estás sacando por el `serial` que tienes definido

Comment: Muchas gracias, sí me sirvió. Descargué Putty, pero me saca valores cada un segundo, sabes como hacer una medición correcta? que me saque los valores como si fuera en la pantalla que no me funciona?

Comment: Eso ocurre por el `delay(1000)` que tienes en tu bucle. Quítalo, modifica el valor.. has lo que quieras con ello, pero que sepas que ese es el motivo por el cuál te están saliendo los datos cada segundo.